# Apache Nifi: Insert / Update into redshift is slow

Tags: apache-nifi

In my ETL process, I'm trying to load final resultsets into AWS Redshift. I'm aware that PutDatabaseRecord inserts/updates the data in bulk. But I've verified on redshift that it is executing one statement at a time. For an average of 150 records, it's taking 1.5 minutes. Attaching a screenshot of multiple inserts.

[image]

Below is my configuration:

[image]

I have primary key in table, also the same field is sort key aswell.
Am I missing anything?

**Update-1:**
Added below debug logger into logback.xml and restarted server to see logs

```
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord" level="DEBUG" />
```

The logs are as below:

```
2021-12-17 12:39:05,780 INFO [NiFi Web Server-19] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Running once PutDatabaseRecord[id=1180157e-118d-1002-61b2-83024a97a793]
2021-12-17 12:39:05,780 INFO [NiFi Web Server-19] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Starting PutDatabaseRecord[id=1180157e-118d-1002-61b2-83024a97a793]
2021-12-17 12:39:05,804 WARN [NiFi Web Server-19] org.apache.nifi.audit.ProcessorAuditor Unable to record actions: null
2021-12-17 12:39:06,544 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@25c348b5 // Another save pending = false
2021-12-17 12:39:06,603 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord PutDatabaseRecord[id=1180157e-118d-1002-61b2-83024a97a793] Fetched Table Schema TableSchema[columns=[ --- data for around 40 columns --- ] for table name orders
2021-12-17 12:50:30,411 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Stopping PutDatabaseRecord[id=1180157e-118d-1002-61b2-83024a97a793]
2021-12-17 12:50:30,411 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Stopping processor: PutDatabaseRecord[id=1180157e-118d-1002-61b2-83024a97a793]
```

It can be seen that it is taking more than 10-15 minutes for a thousand records.

PS: `Maximum Batch Size` is set to 1000, still the execution is happening row after row. Screenshot attached below:
[image]

Comment: just interesting - what is the meaning of number 593, 769, ... in a report and how full insert statement looks like? does it contain values or placeholders instead of values?

Comment: @daggett - the numbers are auto generated query numbers. Everytime a query run on redshift an object with auto generated number is created (that's out of topic). It contains place holders

Comment: try to set debug logger for putdatabaserecord `<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord" level="DEBUG" />` and check how many batches executed for one flow file. there should be messages in log file like this: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/support/nifi-1.15/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/PutDatabaseRecord.java#L780

Comment: @daggett - I've added logger and updated question. Can't see any message from the code base reference.

Comment: screenshot is saying that you are using nifi 1.15.0. and according to documentation there is a parameter `Maximum Batch Size` for version 1.14.0, 1.15.1, but not for 1.15.0 - that is really strange. could you try the same with 1.15.1? are those records are coming through single flow file?

Comment: Redshift is not designed to work efficiently like this, with INSERT/UPDATE SQL statements, you should use COPY statements to ingest data and have your own custom UPSERT/MERGE logic as Redshift is not really a relational database with constraints.

Comment: @B.Pesevski - I understand we can't make transactional insert / update on redshift. Hence to tackle it I've batched the incoming flowfile content in nifi to a 1000 rows batch (initially to check, it'll be increased to 10k). After batching also execution happening at individual rows.

Comment: @daggett - the parameter Maximum Batch Size is present in 1.15.0 as well. It's not seen in the screenshot. But If I scroll it's there and I've set it to 1000. Still it wok's the same way by inserting row by row

Comment: @daggett - question added with `Max Batch Size` sceenshot.

Comment: @Jake you didn't understand me, doing batched INSERT/UPDATE is an anti-pattern when working with Redshift and you will never get the performance you expect. Do COPY statement it will INSERT the data in milliseconds, for UPDATE you will need a more complex COPY with UPSERT/MERGE.

Comment: what is strange - that you don't have batch related debug messages in logs. try to set batch for smaller size then rows in avro. for example 50. BTW are rows coming in as one flow file?

Comment: Also, you can't see in Redshift dashboard the whole parent query, the numbers 593, 769 are the single child INSERT queries from the batch. PutDatabaseRecord  and Redshift should not be used if performance is needed.

Comment: @daggett - yes rows are coming in one flow file. Verified content and `record.count` attribute also. It's 1000.

Comment: @B.Pesevski is there any reference where I can push data into local file system / s3 and automate merge/insert to redshift. I read multiple articles, no concrete solution given from `nifi -> s3/local file -> redshift`

Comment: @daggett - I've introduced `SplitAvro` with `Output Size` = 50
This resulted in comparatively faster execution (1000 records - 8 Mins : 20 * 50 records - 4 Mins). Not getting what's happening. Checked for log for batching log, not found though

Comment: @Jake I can't find any reference, maybe I can write one blog post. The flows I have do all in nifi `datasource -> convertToCSV -> Compress -> PutS3 -> GenerateCopyStatement -> ExecuteSql -> DeleteS3`

To prepare the Copy Statement you will need to know the CSV format (you control this) and the S3path. So I use custom script processor for this.

Comment: Also you will need this at some point you will need to do Upserts for sure:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html

Comment: @B.Pesevski I have gone through the flow you mentioned in above connect and the comment before too. To create `GenerateCopyStatement` I haven't created a custom script so far. Please refer any exising example to do so and issue a copy command.

Comment: @Jake I've created custom processor for this, that is working with Velocity templates in Java and evaluates Velocity template with NiFi attributes and outputs SQL statements. But you can create something similar with any of the scripting languages supported in ExecuteScript processor if you are not comfortable to write custom processor in Java. 
Here is nice article for using the ExecuteScript processor https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922